# How to transfer data from MacBook Pro 2014(SSD) to MacBook Pro 2016

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

Hello I have a liquid damage on my MacBook Pro 15inch ( 2014 ) I brought it to service center and they told probably some motherboard issue, but they checked SSD Card and it's completely fine.

I bought the new 2016 MB Pro 15 Retina and now I Need to Transfer data, I have only SSD chip from old computer. Can I somehow Migrate all data from old SSD to new SSD? I know that  I`m not able to physically replace them.
But is there any tools which will help to transfer data from external SSD?

I need to get all data, profile etc. on my new MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

If your old SSD has been removed from the old MBP, then you're best bet is to purchase an external enclosure for you to place it in.

Once you've done that you can connect it to your new MacBook Pro and access it like any external drive. At this point you can choose how you want to transfer the data. Probably the easiest will be to use the Migration Assistant app. For more information read [Move your content to a new Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204350).

In terms of the external enclosure you will need to purchase one that can connect to your new MBP, although you may already have various adapters or dongles etc that you can use to connect to USB drives, etc. However, since your old SSD is fine, I'd suggest you get an enclosure you can use all the time (one with the right connection for your scenario) as you'd then have a fast external SSD you can keep using.

You can purchase a suitable enclosure online or from most dedicated computer retailers.

Comment: I would recommend this OWC product or something similar. It costs about $100 from B&H, but not only will it work to transfer the data, you can then then use the old SSD as an external storage disk! http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1213001-REG

Comment: @NoahL Yes, that'd be a good choice, especially for longer term use!

Comment: That external drive can then be used for a Time Machine backup.  Something you *should* have already...hint, hint.

Comment: is it m.2 or msata?